# Web application written with Processing, using processing.js: how to debug?

Tags: processing, processing.js

I'm a newby in HTML, while I've some skill with Processing language.
I'm writing an application in Processing which I want to visualise in a local webpage.
I've a basic index.html, which upload my sketch and the file processing.js.
It works.

My problem is that sometimes, an application which runs with no proiblem using the Processing IDE, does not run in the webpage. I assume there are still some bugs in the porting from Processing to JavaScript.
What I would like to know is: is there some way to debug the webpage I try to visualise?
Just to seek "where" the webpage remains stuck! In this way I could bypass the problem!
For now, I'm using Firefox for html visualisation.
Thanks a lot, Valerio

Comment: This is the first result for googling "firefox javascript debugger": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Answer (score 2):

Ops solved! I downloaded FireBug, an add-on for Firefox implementing a debugger. 
Then I launched the debugger. It showed me immediately the error.
For curious people:

I declared an ArrayList called "foo_list", containing object "foo":

`ArrayList<foo>foo_list`

The above line does not produce any error in the Processing IDE.
However processing.js complains with it, the debugger displayng
the following message:

```
ReferenceError: ArrayListfoo_list" is not defined
```

The solution is to insert a blank space:

```
ArrayList<foo> foo_list;
```

This works! Maybe the error given to the parser
from Processing to JavaScript!
Bye!

Comment: you shouldn't need firebug, Firefox and Chrome already come with webdev consoles. Just use `cmd-option-i` on a mac, or `ctrl-shift-i` on windows and there you are.